# How Can I make a common code method in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've a stored procedure which is working fine. My problem is that I'm repeating a dynamic query to use it 3 times:-

```
    --For Note
    SET @TblMaterial = 'ClassNote'
    SET @ColMaterialID = 'ClassNoteID'
    SET @ColMaterialFK = 'ClassNoteFK'              
    SET @cmdForMaterial = N'UPDATE '+@TblMaterial+' Set Status_Info = 0 where '+@ColMaterialID+' in ( Select s.'+@ColMaterialFK+' from  '+@RelTbl+' s where s.' +  @ColForFK + ' = ' +  @MainID + ' AND s.ClassSubjectFK IN ( SELECT T.ClassSubjectFK FROM ' + @RelTbl + ' T WHERE  T.'+@ColForFK+' = '+ @MainID + ') and s.ClassSubjectFK NOT IN ( SELECT E.ClassSubjectFK FROM ' +@RelTbl+' E WHERE E.'+@ColForFK+' != '+ @MainID +') and s.'+@ColMaterialFK+'  is not null )'
    EXEC(@cmdForMaterial)

    --For EBook
    SET @TblMaterial = 'ClassEbook'
    SET @ColMaterialID = 'ClassEbookID'
    SET @ColMaterialFK = 'ClassEbookFK'
    SET @cmdForMaterial = N'UPDATE '+@TblMaterial+' Set Status_Info = 0 where '+@ColMaterialID+' in ( Select s.'+@ColMaterialFK+' from  '+@RelTbl+' s where s.' +  @ColForFK + ' = ' +  @MainID + ' AND s.ClassSubjectFK IN ( SELECT T.ClassSubjectFK FROM ' + @RelTbl + ' T WHERE  T.'+@ColForFK+' = '+ @MainID + ') and s.ClassSubjectFK NOT IN ( SELECT E.ClassSubjectFK FROM ' +@RelTbl+' E WHERE E.'+@ColForFK+' != '+ @MainID +') and s.'+@ColMaterialFK+'  is not null )'
    EXEC(@cmdForMaterial)

    --For SP
    SET @TblMaterial = 'ClassSamplePaper'
    SET @ColMaterialID = 'ClassSamplePaperID'
    SET @ColMaterialFK = 'ClassSPFK'
    SET @cmdForMaterial = N'UPDATE '+@TblMaterial+' Set Status_Info = 0 where '+@ColMaterialID+' in ( Select s.'+@ColMaterialFK+' from  '+@RelTbl+' s where s.' +  @ColForFK + ' = ' +  @MainID + ' AND s.ClassSubjectFK IN ( SELECT T.ClassSubjectFK FROM ' + @RelTbl + ' T WHERE  T.'+@ColForFK+' = '+ @MainID + ') and s.ClassSubjectFK NOT IN ( SELECT E.ClassSubjectFK FROM ' +@RelTbl+' E WHERE E.'+@ColForFK+' != '+ @MainID +') and s.'+@ColMaterialFK+'  is not null )'
    EXEC(@cmdForMaterial)
```

I was just wondering is there any way out so that I can set this code :-

```
SET @cmdForMaterial = N'UPDATE '+@TblMaterial+' Set Status_Info = 0 where '+@ColMaterialID+' in ( Select s.'+@ColMaterialFK+' from  '+@RelTbl+' s where s.' +  @ColForFK + ' = ' +  @MainID + ' AND s.ClassSubjectFK IN ( SELECT T.ClassSubjectFK FROM ' + @RelTbl + ' T WHERE  T.'+@ColForFK+' = '+ @MainID + ') and s.ClassSubjectFK NOT IN ( SELECT E.ClassSubjectFK FROM ' +@RelTbl+' E WHERE E.'+@ColForFK+' != '+ @MainID +') and s.'+@ColMaterialFK+'  is not null )'
```

once and use it multiple times?

Comment: This is procedural thinking... Try to find a set-based approach... Look for `JOIN`, maybe `updateable CTE`... Why do you have the need to set table and column names dynamically? All of this smells heavily...

Comment: Could you please add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: That is already a common code. You may extract that concatenation to another internal SP. You probably might want to go further to code generation approach if CRUD methods for your solution are so predictable.

Comment: You could encapsulate the dynamic UPDATE statement in parameterized proc and execute it 3 times, passing the table and column names.

Comment: I agree with Shungo. In fact, I would even go one step further and claim that the fact you have these almost identical statements suggest a broken database design. Seem to me like you have too many table with the same structure describing similar things that you need to unite - Judging from the code you posted only, `ClassNote`, `ClassEbook` and `ClassSamplePaper` should all be in the same table, with an added column to tell if the row describes  a Note, an Ebook or Sample Paper.

Comment: When you meet [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) ask him to help stamp out SQL injection.

Comment: Thank You All for Your Time. @DanGuzman Yes Iam working on the parametrized SP for now.

Comment: @ZoharPeled The 3 tables have been separated as there will be millions of data inside each one of them.My guess was that If it'll be a single table then query will be slower with 3 million data. Hence separated them.

Comment: @Deepak How many millions are we talking about? 10? 100? When properly designed and indexed, SQL Server can handle tables this size, even quite easily.

Comment: So you mean to say my single table with 100 million data won't effect the performance of my query? Can you share any link showing properly designed and indexed table structure? Any help will be grateful.

Comment: @Deepak this is all very general, so I can't give you any specific link. Start with websites like https://www.mssqltips.com/, https://sqlperformance.com/, http://www.sqlservercentral.com/.

Comment: Also, read about [Partitioned Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes) and [Filtered Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using dynamic query, you can write simple update statements which will be more manageable.

If you can't change it to normal update queries in that case you can go
for a stored procedure with desired parameters and call it multiple time with different parameters.

**Not Recommended :**
Still if you can't opt of any of the above options, you can try like following.

```
  CREATE TABLE  #T(
  [Index] INT Identity ,ColMaterialID VARCHAR(100)
   , ColMaterialFK  VARCHAR(100),TblMaterial VARCHAR(100)
  )


INSERT INTO  #T(ColMaterialID,ColMaterialFK,TblMaterial)
SELECT 'ClassNote','ClassNoteID','ClassNoteFK'  

--Insert Remaning values 


WHILE(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #T) > 0
BEGIN
 --Read the top 1 from temp table
 --Build the Query and Execute
 --Remove the processed entiry

END
```

Comment: This is a terrible choice. Not only is looping in SQL should be avoided whenever possible, It also perpetuates the design mistakes that caused the problem in the first place.

Comment: I agree with you that's why i suggested to use separate stored procedure to do this.

Comment: If you agree this is a terrible choice, why posting it as an answer in the first place?

Comment: Thanks @PSK . For now I'm working with a Parametrised SP to execute my statement.

Comment: That will be easy to implement and maintainable option